# How to use sorted() method to sort a list of pairs?

Tags: python, sorting

> Define a function, `histo(s)` computing the histogram of a given
>   string. Characters must appear in the list ordered from **least**
>   frequent to **most** frequent. For example, `histo('implemented')` is
>   `[('t', 1), ('p', 1), ('n', 1), ('l', 1), ('i', 1), ('d', 1), ('m',
>   2), ('e', 3)]`. (Characters with the same frequency must appear in
>   **decreasing** alphabetical order.) To implement the sorting, use the python built-in function `sorted`.

Here is my work:

```
def keyf(p):
    x,y = p
    return (y,x)

s = "implemented"
d = {}
for c in s:
    d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
dlist = list(d.items())
dlist = sorted(dlist, key = keyf, reverse = False)
```

After I ran it, the dlist is `[('d', 1), ('i', 1), ('l', 1), ('n', 1), ('p', 1), ('t', 1), ('m', 2), ('e', 3)]`. the problem is the first element of the pair with the same frequency is not in descending order, how do I fix this?
I've tried to put

```
dlist = sorted(dlist, reverse = True)
```

in the end, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show the result you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the result you want is -

[('t', 1), ('p', 1), ('n', 1), ('l', 1), ('i', 1), ('d', 1), ('m', 2), ('e', 3)]

In that case, there are two conditions on which you need to sort, *ascending order of frequency* and *descending order of the alphbet* (for same frequency) . For that, you need to change the first to *descending order of negative frequency* , making both sort conditions in descending order, and then sort the complete list in descending order (Or you can do the opposite, and sort complete list in ascending order). Example -

```
>>> def keyf(p):
...     x,y = p
...     return (-y,x)
...
>>> s = "implemented"
>>> d = {}
>>> for c in s:
...     d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
...
>>>
>>> dlist = list(d.items())
>>> dlist = sorted(dlist, key = keyf, reverse = True)
>>> print(dlist)
[('t', 1), ('p', 1), ('n', 1), ('l', 1), ('i', 1), ('d', 1), ('m', 2), ('e', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the order of the characters in the key function:

```
def keyf(p):
    x,y = p
    return (y,-ord(x))
```

Comment: pretty staight forward, thanks for reminding using ord()

Answer (score 1):

Custom key is passed to `sorted` function. To achieve decreasing alphabetical order letter is converted to ascii code by `ord` and negated.

```
from collections import Counter

def histo(s):
    c = Counter(s)
    return sorted(c.iteritems(), key=lambda item: (item[1], -ord(item[0])))

expected = [('t', 1), ('p', 1), ('n', 1), ('l', 1), ('i', 1), ('d', 1), ('m', 2), ('e', 3)]
assert histo('implemented') == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cmp function for double sorting:

```
>>> aList
[('d', 1), ('e', 3), ('i', 1), ('l', 1), ('m', 2), ('n', 1), ('p', 1), ('t', 1)]
>>> sorted(aList, cmp = lambda x, y: cmp(x[1],y[1]) if cmp(x[1],y[1]) else cmp(y[0],x[0]))
[('t', 1), ('p', 1), ('n', 1), ('l', 1), ('i', 1), ('d', 1), ('m', 2), ('e', 3)]
```